# Matching a line and printing lines above

Tags: perl, pattern-matching, match

Code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $file = $ARGV[0];
my $position = $ARGV[1]; # POSITION OF THE RESIDUE

open (FILE, $file);

while (<FILE>) {
my @f = split;
if (($f[0] == "ANNOT_RESID_NO") && ($f[1] == $position)){
    push @line, $_;
}
}
print @line;
close(FILE);
```

INPUT :

```
ANNOT_TYPE[1] 0
ANNOT_TYPE_NAME[1] CATRES
ANNOT_NUMBER[1][1] 1
ANNOT_NAME[1][1] 3.1.3.16
ANNOT_DESC[1][1] Phosphoprotein phosphatase.
ANNOT_RESID_NO[1][1][1] 91
ANNOT_RESID_NAME[1][1][1] ASP
ANNOT_RESID_NUM[1][1][1]   95 
ANNOT_RESID_NO[1][1][2] 92
ANNOT_RESID_NAME[1][1][2] ARG
ANNOT_NRESID[1][1] 6
ANNOT_NUMBER[1][2] 2
ANNOT_NAME[1][2] 3.1.3.53
ANNOT_DESC[1][2] [Myosin-light-chain] phosphatase.
ANNOT_RESID_NO[1][2][1] 91
ANNOT_RESID_NAME[1][2][1] ASP
ANNOT_RESID_NUM[1][2][1]   95 
ANNOT_RESID_NO[1][2][2] 92
ANNOT_RESID_NAME[1][2][2] ARG
```

Question :

I am printing the line with has $position(for example 91) for the line starting with "ANNOT_RESID_NO". Along with this line, I also want to print, every time, in @line is the first line above this match containing "ANNOT_DESC". This "ANNOT_DESC" line is not necessarily always the line just above my matched line.

Answer (score 1):

Try (complete code):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = $ARGV[0];
my $position = $ARGV[1];

open (FILE, $file) or die $!;

my $desc;

my @line;

while (<FILE>) {
    my @f = split " ";

    if ( $f[0] =~ /^ANNOT_DESC/ ) {
        $desc = $_;
        next;
    }


    if ( $f[0] =~ /^ANNOT_RESID_NO/  and $f[1] == $position ) {
        push @line, $desc, $_;
    }
}
```

output:

```
ANNOT_DESC[1][1] Phosphoprotein phosphatase.
ANNOT_RESID_NO[1][1][1] 91
ANNOT_DESC[1][2] [Myosin-light-chain] phosphatase.
ANNOT_RESID_NO[1][2][1] 91
```

Comment: This doesn't print the $desc when I print finally the @line.

Comment: Can you please post your output?

Comment: You should probably set $desc to empty string before the next iteration ($desc="";).

Answer (score 0):

With a data set that small you can push the lines from the file to an array(e.g. @file_data) , iterate the @file_data array and push the values you want into your @line array.

Comment: The data set is actually quite large. I just posted a few lines of it. Also, I am stumped about how to do a match that keeps going above till it matches the ""ANNOT_DESC", saves that line and then again continues going down the file to keep searching for the next "ANNOT_RESID_NO 91".

Comment: Why the down mod?  Your post indicated "INPUT:" not "PARTIAL INPUT:" or "SUBSET OF INPUT:"

Comment: Apologies if it was confusing. Down mode cause it has to grab all instances of "ANNOT_RESID_NO $position" existing in the file.

Comment: Unbelievable that the person asking the question would downvote an answer when the original question was so poorly worded that the answerer missed an *un-specified* point. Shameful abuse of those trying to help.

Comment: @DavidO : I had apologized for that and actually posted a fresh question with all the editing after his comment  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888987/matching-a-line-looking-for-a-pattern-again-above-this-matched-and-printing-all#comment15822407_11888987). Yet, when one uses "for example 91", I think that means that its just an example with both having 91. If only the world was as perfect... :)